# What can you do when you can't chmod /system/bin/chmod?

Tags: permissions

I have changed the permissions of the file \system\bin\chmod from 777(-rwxrwxrwx) to 644 (-rw-r--r--), how can I turn back to 777?

I don't know is this may be relevant, but I'm using a samsung J5 running android 9.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There are multiple options. See my comment to the answer. Don't set it to 777. It's too open. 755 is enough for executable files.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder how you can change `/system` without read-write access. Usually a reboot will restore permissions, but you can also change it on-the-fly

`chmod` is most likely a symlink to `toybox` and you have changed permissions of toybox instead. this will affect most (if not all) of the commands. you can maybe fix this with [busybox](https://www.busybox.net/downloads/binaries/1.31.0-defconfig-multiarch-musl)

**external MicroSD Card** permissions are `-rwxrwx--x` per default, so maybe this trick works (untested). copy binary to external MicroSD Card first, then move the file into `/data/local/tmp` (moving a file does keep permissions)

```
adb push busybox-armv7l /sdcard/busybox
adb shell
su
ls -1 /storage
cp /sdcard/busybox /storage/????-????
cd /data/local/tmp
mv /storage/????-????/busybox .
./busybox mount -o remount,rw /
./busybox chmod a+x /system/bin/toybox
```

if you really just changed permissions of `chmod` (which must a binary in this case) you can just use toybox applets with prefix `toybox chmod`

---

in case `ls` `mount` `cp` and `mv` not working, run the following commands in [termux](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux) (thx @ Irfan Latif)

```
pkg install busybox
su
export PATH=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin:$PATH
busybox mount -o remount,rw /
busybox chmod a+x /system/bin/toybox
```

Comment: `x` permission on emulated storage is only for directories (for traversal) not for files (for execution). On Android 8+ usually `vendor` partition has its own toybox binary. Using Termux would be another straightforward option. Installing busybox apps from PlayStore is another option. And if tar isn't a toybox applet on device, busybox binary can also be extracted from a tar archive which would preserve permissions.

Comment: External SD cards are also exposed to apps as emulated storage. You may please edit your answer to include the details.